# Poner el simbolo ● en java

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda para saber como escribir este simbolo en java (●). He probado usando el unicode de esta [página](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CF/index.htm) pero no funciona. Muchas gracias

Comment: por favor comparte el código para saber como lo intentaste

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] y modifica tu pregunta , ¿Quieres escribir este carácter en el código o imprimirlo programaticamente?

Comment: No le pongas CERRADO. Al título. De tu pregunta, eso no es válido, acepta en cambio la respuesta de quien te ayudo dando clic en la palomita que está a lado

Answer (score 1):

He probado con el unicode y me ha dado exactamente el mismo problema que a ti, no mostraba nada más que un simple símbolo de pregunta

He puesto directamente el símbolo en el sout

```
System.out.println("•");
```

y me ha saltando el siguiente problema

[image: Problema símbolo]

Simplemente le he dado a **Save as UFT-8**

Y al momento de volver a correr el código ya lo reconocía y lo imprimía directamente con el símbolo o con el unicode

```
System.out.println("\u25CF");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola si la respuesta a resuelto tu pregunta, selecciónala como respuesta correcta, saludos amigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el caracter viñeta: (•)
Se obtiene con alt+0149

Comment: Me funcionó. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Que tal prueba con la siguiente linea: Java source code

```
System.out.println("\u25CF");
```

Comment: Al escribir eso que me has puesto tú (que es lo que tenía) me aparace una interrogación (?).

Comment: Que tipo de codificación tienes en tu java? prueba poniendo la que yo tengo:
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
o
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: La codificación es Cp1252. He probado lo que me has puesto y no me funciona

Answer (score -1):

suponiendo que el problema no sea El formato del Archivo de codigo Fuente (.java este en un formato que no sea Unicode, por ejemplo Ansii)

este caso no se Debe a Java, sino al applicativo que utilizas para desplegar el "Output" por ejemplo, si Utilizas un IDE Netbeans, Eclipse, Jidea, etc. es posible que estos si te muestren el resultado correcto. para muestra:

[image: muestra en IDE]

yo utilizo Windows 7. desde la terminal de Windows (CMD) o en CygWin ambos me muestran un carracter que no es el que deseo:

[image: cmd]

realizando una revision con respecto a este aspecto encontre los siguiente: [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line) en esta pregunta en StackOverflow en ingles nos muestra que Windows (CMD) posee un problema para mostrar caracters Unicode en Consola y para solucionarlo requiere hacer cambios que pueden o no causar otro tipo de problemas.

en mi caso para solucionar este problema utilize Cygwin o Powershell dado que mediante CMD no me fue posible hacer que mostrara el caracter correcto:

[image: funcionalidad correcta]

como se puede observar el resultado esperado es desplegado cuando se utiliza el parametro -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 [sobre el comando chcp](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) y propiedad [Dfile.encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031877/jvm-property-dfile-encoding-utf8-or-utf-8)

esto tambien puede ser utilizado en Powershell para solucionar el problema ahi:

[image: solucion en Poweshell]

Comment: Guau! eso es demasiado jajaja

Comment: que puedo decir me gusta ir a lo profundo de los problemas (asi tenga que desarmar el Carro para ver que lo que le falta es aceite) XD